# How to add a comment on a video using youtube API??? Can someone show me how to do it right?

Tags: vb.net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I'm making a desktop application in VB.NET that will interact with YouTube. So far I have managed to solve the "problem" of OAuth2 authentication and I have my tokens (auth and refresh). I need to refresh the auth token once every hour but this is not the problem.

I tried to post a comment on a video in many ways, using the http POST and using the YouTube API. On the HTTP request POST I get a "bad request" response and on the YouTube API try I get nothing, no comment posted and no errors. How can I do this? The documentation for the YouTube Data API is corrupted and I can't open it or install it on Visual Studio so I do my tests by trial and error using the little examples that people posted online.

This is the code that I used for the HTTP version:

```
'create the xml comment as in API example
Dim ContentLenght As Long
Dim xmlData As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
Dim commentXML As XDocument =
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
<content><%= comment %></content>
</entry>

ContentLenght = commentXML.ToString.Length

'---------------------------------------------------------
'create the POST request to submit the comment

Dim sentXml As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(commentXML.ToString)
Dim url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" & videoID & "/comments"
Dim req As New WebClient
req.Headers.Add("Host: gdata.youtube.com")
req.Headers.Add("Length:" & ContentLenght)
req.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/atom+Xml")
req.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " & Token)
req.Headers.Add("GData-Version: 2")
req.Headers.Add("X-GData-Key: key=" & developerKey)
Dim response As Byte() = req.UploadData(url, "POST", sentXml)
```

The API code that I tried is:

```
Dim commentingSettings As New YouTubeRequestSettings(appName, developerKey, Token)
Dim lcommentingRequest As New YouTubeRequest(commentingSettings)

Dim video As New Video()
video.VideoId = "JEvV0RHMU-Y"
Dim comm As New Comment
comm.Content = "comm text here"

lcommentingRequest.AddComment(video, comm)
```

Comment: I made those edits because your version of the question had a considerable amount of cruft. Stack Overflow is not a forum where such things are typical; it's a site where *content* is what matters.

Comment: I see... well I also see that many of the good questions remain unanswered, may be people need to know more then the code that represent the problem to be determined to act and share their knowledge... but is ok anyway :)

Comment: At this point, your latest edit should be put in an answer, and then you should probably ask a new question, based upon that, about how to get the comment ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem using the Youtube API. The problem was the way the "video" object is created. Here is the working code for people that need it:

```
Dim commentingSettings As New YouTubeRequestSettings(appName, developerKey, Token)
Dim lcommentingRequest As New YouTubeRequest(commentingSettings)

Dim videodUrl As New Uri(String.Format("{0}/{1}",Google.GData.YouTube.YouTubeQuery.DefaultVideoUri, "BtrFZmZjalE"))
Dim video As Google.YouTube.Video = request.Retrieve(Of Google.YouTube.Video)(videoEdUrl)

Dim comm As New Comment
comm.Content = "comm text here"

lcommentingRequest.AddComment(video, comm)
```

Now the code will work!

The new question is: How do I get the comment ID after I posted? Is there a way to get it from the code above (some server response or something)? ... but as Chris M. suggested I will create another question for this...

Answer (score 0):

YouTube API v3 doesn't have support for comments as of now. Only v2 supports. Hope there may be one in future.

Comment: :) you did not made your homework :)) ... in v3 there is no support for comments but there is in v2 and v2 is working fine...

Comment: I have solved the problem using the Youtube API. The problem was the way the "video" object is created. I'll attache the code to the main question